# Can apply() delete the this of a method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, this, apply

Please, compare the following functions:

```js
function maxOver2DArr(arr){
    return arr.map(sub => {
        return Math.max.apply(null, sub)
    })
}
const arr1 = [[13, 27, 18, 26], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]

console.log(maxOver2DArr(arr1)); //[ 27, 1001 ]
```

```js
function maxOver2DArr(arr){
    return arr.map(sub => {
        return Math.max.apply(Array, sub)
    })
}
const arr1 = [[13, 27, 18, 26], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]

console.log(maxOver2DArr(arr1)); //[ 27, 1001 ]
```

Is true that I'm sort of deleting the this of Math.max (Math), while setting the this of Math.max to Array in the second one?

Comment: `Math.max` doesn't care about its `this` value, so why would it matter?

Comment: You are calling the function with the “wrong” (different) `this` value compared to `Math.max(x, y, z)` in both cases, yes, but `Math.max` doesn’t care.

Comment: "*Is true that I'm sort of deleting the this of Math.max*" - no. A method does not have a `this` value. There is nothing to be deleted. A method *call* will have a `this` value, but `Math.max.apply(…)` does not call the `max` method, it calls the `apply` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so , the first argument is the value of `this` in the function on which `apply` is being called, in this case that function is `Math.max`

but `Math.max` does not even use the value of `this` so it doesn't matter what you pass as first argument to `apply` and hence the result is same